# Creating a variable whose property must satisfy a constraint

Tags: swift, types, enums, properties, constraints

I have an enum: `MyEnum`.

```
enum MyEnum {
  case One
  case Two
}
```

Then I have a class that has a property of type `MyEnum`.

```
class MyClass {
  var myEnum: MyEnum

  init(myEnum: MyEnum) {
    self.myEnum = myEnum
  }
}
```

Now I have a variable of type `MyClass` whose `MyEnum` property must be `One`. This is the part that I don't know how to do.

```
var myVar: MyClass where { self.myEnum == .One } = MyClass(myEnum: .One) // doesn't work
```

The following shouldn't work just like `var myInt: Int = "Hello World"` doesn't work.

```
var myVar: MyClass where { self.myEnum == .One } = MyClass(myEnum: .Two)
```

Comment: How about `var myVar: MyClass where { self.myEnum == .One } = MyClass(Bool.random() ? .One : .Two)`? Should it compile or not? How does the compiler know in advance whether the parameter is `.One` or `.Two` if I randomly choose between them?

Answer (score 0):

**Step One:** I think we will need to use an assert

```swift
var myVar: MyClass = MyClass(.One); assert(myVar.myEnum == .One)
```

---

**Step 2:** I really like the *willSet*

```swift
var myVar: Int? {
    willSet(to) { assert(to == 0) }
}
myVar = 0 // good
myVar = 1 // breaks
```

---

**Step 3:** Apply it to your class:

```swift
enum MyEnum {
    case One, Two
}
class MyClass {
    var mustBe: [MyEnum]
    var myEnum: MyEnum {
        willSet(to) { assert(mustBe.contains(to)) }
    }

    init(_ myEnum: MyEnum,_ mustBe: [MyEnum]) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
        self.mustBe = mustBe
        assert(mustBe.contains(myEnum))
    }
}

var myVar = MyClass(.One, [.One]) // good
myVar.myEnum = .One // good
myVar.myEnum = .Two // breaks
```